# How to define finite set of 5 elements in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am trying to construct a type in TypeScript that denotes a finite set using other types, let's say of exactly 5 values?(And it's not enum).

For example :

```
Boolean = {TRUE,FALSE}
```

Comment: `type T = A | B | C | D | E;`? Or `type BOOLEAN = "TRUE" | "FALSE";`?

Comment: @torazaburo, If you looking at types as sets, your type contain the flowing type: type T = A | B | C | D | E |F; i.e. it's a sub type. I need a type that contain exactly five values and have no sub types that contains more.

Comment: I don't understand your question and think there may be some confusion between your use of "type" and "value". What exactly is it about `type BOOLEAN = "TRUE" | "FALSE";` that doesn't accomplish what you want?

Comment: It does, thank you.As you said there was a confusion between "type" and value. Thanks again,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a literal union type. Example:

```
type LiteralType = "ONE" | 2 | "Three" | 4 | "5";
```

Any variable declared as `LiteralType` can only have one of the above five values:

```
let x: LiteralType;
x = 2; // OK
x = "Two"; // Error
```

Union/literal types documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html